# In source code, function is called with no (). Documentation gives 1 required argument

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I'm working on learning OpenGL development and while working through some example source code there's a line that I can't seem to make sense of. It involves initialization of GLAD with GLFW. Below is the whole block of code.

```
if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
{
    std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
```

So, as far as I can tell, the code in the if statement is designed to initialize GLAD and return a 1 if the initialization is successful allowing easy error handling. Cool. Where I am confused though, is the input to this `gladLoadGLLoader` function, which is:

```
(GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress
```

Doing a bit of research, GLADloadproc returned nothing useful, but `glfwGetProcAddress` has an entry in the GLFW documentation [here](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__context.html#ga35f1837e6f666781842483937612f163), and according this, it is a function and defines 1 required argument. I thought this was weird because in the source code it doesn't even look like a function; it looks like `glfwGetProcAddress` is a variable (or object perhaps?) being cast to a type of `GLADloadproc`. Doing a bit of introspection, I ran the following prints:

```
std::cout << glfwGetProcAddress << std::endl;
std::cout << typeid(glfwGetProcAddress).name() << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
00AE1172
void (__cdec*__cdecl(char const *))(void)
```

So I can see that calling `glfwGetProcAddress` as it is does in fact return something that looks like an address, but attempting to call it as `glfwGetProcAddress()` fails and not shockingly needs an argument. And when looking at the type of this supposed address it is something I definitely do not understand. So I'm fine with using this as clearly it works and is referenced directly in official documentation as well as tutorials, but I'd really like to understand what's going on here if anyone happens do have a better idea than I do.

Comment: `glfwGetProcAddress` takes a name and returns the address of a function (if found). `gladLoadGLLoader` is using a level of indirection (taking the function to lookup the address of a function) so it can be replaced if required. see: http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__context.html#ga35f1837e6f666781842483937612f163

Comment: You're right! You *do* need `()` (and an argument) to call the function. Therefore this code isn't calling the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL extensions (and on some operating systems every function not defined in the OpenGL 1.1 profile) have to be [loaded at runtime](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions). This means that one has to query the address of each of these functions through the appropriate operating system api (wgl/glx/...). The result is than a [function pointer](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html) that can be used to call the function.

GLAD is now a library that handles this function pointer loading for you. But in order to be able to query the function pointer it needs to know which method should be used to retrieve them (as already said, this is operation system/window api dependent). The first argument to `gladLoadGLLoader` is a function pointer to a function used to retrieve OpenGL function pointer by name. `gladLoadGLLoader` then calls this function (pointer) to query other function pointer.

In case of glfw, the function used is `glfwGetProcAddress` but one could also pass `glutGetProcAddress` when working with glut or `SDL_GL_GetProcAddress` when working with SDL.

Comment: Okay I believe I am understanding now, but what is the `GLADloadproc` preceding `glfwGetProcAddress`?

Comment: This casts the function pointer of `glfwGetProcAddress`  to the function pointer type `gladLoadGLLoader` expects. I'm not 100% sure if you even need this or if `&glfwGetProcAddress` works too.

Comment: Okay I was pretty sure it was something like that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

`typedef void* (* GLADloadproc)(const char *name);`

That's not just any old pointer type: that's a *function* pointer type.  In your code, you *call* the function `gladLoadGLLoader`, but *pass the address of* `glfwGetProcAddress`.  `gladLoadGLLoader` now gets to call the argument you passed it, any time it wants to, and with whatever argument it wants to.  You yourself are not actually calling `glfwGetProcAddress`.

In this context, `glfwGetProcAddress` is a 'callback', and `gladLoadGLLoader` registers that callback.